# R: Get row values based on column name in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID Q4_1 Q4_2 Q4_3 Q4_4 Q4_5
1  4    3    1
2  1    3
3  3    1    2
4  5
```

Can I know how to rearrange the row values based on the column's prefix to have something like this?

```
ID Q4_1 Q4_2 Q4_3 Q4_4 Q4_5
1  1         3    4
2  1         3
3  1    2    3
4                      5
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible (use `dput()` and share the result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach. Note that I've replaced the empty space in your input with `NA`.

The core of this solution is to use `lapply` to go through all rows in the dataframe, then use `ifelse` to match the row values with the `header_suffix` I created, which contains the suffix of `colnames` of the dataframe.

```r
df <- read.table(header = T,
                 text = "ID Q4_1 Q4_2 Q4_3 Q4_4 Q4_5
1  4    3    1  NA  NA
2  1    3 NA  NA  NA
3  3    1    2  NA  NA
4  5  NA  NA  NA  NA")

header_suffix <- gsub("^.+_", "", grep("_", colnames(df), value = T))

header_suffix
#> [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

df2 <-
  cbind(df[, 1], 
        as.data.frame(
          do.call(
            rbind, 
            lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
              ifelse(header_suffix %in% df[x, 2:ncol(df)], header_suffix, NA))
            )
          )
        )

colnames(df2) <- colnames(df)

df2
#>   ID Q4_1 Q4_2 Q4_3 Q4_4 Q4_5
#> 1  1    1 <NA>    3    4 <NA>
#> 2  2    1 <NA>    3 <NA> <NA>
#> 3  3    1    2    3 <NA> <NA>
#> 4  4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Tidyverse approach

```
df %>% pivot_longer(2:6, names_to = "Q", values_to = "no") %>% 
  mutate(new_Q = paste0("Q4_", no)) %>% 
  filter(new_Q != "Q4_NA") %>% 
  select(ID, new_Q, no ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = new_Q, values_from = no) %>% 
  select(ID, Q4_1, Q4_2, Q4_3, Q4_4, Q4_5 )

# A tibble: 4 x 6
     ID  Q4_1  Q4_2  Q4_3  Q4_4  Q4_5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1    NA     3     4    NA
2     2     1    NA     3    NA    NA
3     3     1     2     3    NA    NA
4     4    NA    NA    NA    NA     5
```